# Batch crashes with spaces even with var set and delayed expansion

Tags: batch-file

I just started coding two days ago. (It's oddly addictive). And I started so that I could make a simulated "computer hacking" experience as a portion of an escape room that I am designing. Mainly, I have just been looking around and finding different ideas and putting them together in an aesthetically pleasing way. However, I want to make it crash resistant. So that when people are using it they don't get booted for just button mashing and pressing enter.

I got this to work in the :menu but not on the faux log in page.
Below is the code that I wrote that I want to be able to work on other pages:

```
:menu 
cls 
set "answer=Nothing^!"
set var=%var: =%
echo. 
echo Menu
echo.
echo 1. Login
echo 2. Instructions
echo 3. Exit
echo.
set /p answer=Type the number of your option and press enter: 
echo.
echo.
if /I "!answer!" == "exit" goto exit
echo You answered: %answer%
echo Which is not a valid entry.
echo Try again.
if /I %answer% == 1 goto :Login1  
if /I %answer% == 2 goto :Instructions
if /I %answer% == 3 goto :Exit
if /I %answer% == 43153 goto :done 
pause
goto :menu
```

Here is the code I cannot get to work.

```
:Login2
cls
set "un=Nothing^!"
set "pw=Nothing^!"
set var=%var: =%
echo.
echo Log On
echo.
if %counter% lss 5 echo Password incorrect, %counter% attempts left
echo. 
echo. 
set /p un=Enter your UserID:
set /p pw=Enter your Password:
if /I %un% == ID (
if /I %pw% == PASSWORD goto :loading1 
)
if /I !un! == "exit" ( 
if !pw! == "exit" goto loading2
goto :loading2
```

If I type something random to input such as: asdf asdf
The menu doesn't crash. But the login2 page does. It crashes if it is  username and password OR just username OR just password that have spaces. And if I just "enter" through the screen it does not auto-populate " Nothing^! " like the menu does.

I would paste the entirety of the file below, but because with the decorative liberties I took it won't fit well on this page. And I can't find a place to upload it. But any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Again, thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
if /I "!answer!" == "exit" goto exit
```

is correct

```
if /I %un% == ID (
```

is *syntactically* correct, provided `un` contains a simple string not containing spaces.

if `un` contains `some spaces` then the command is interpreted as

```
if /I some spaces == ID (
```

and the required syntax is

> if [/i] *string1* *operator* *string2* dothis

An operator like `==` is also a string, so `cmd` sees `spaces` where it's expecting an operator, so it protests.

To allow spaces (and other separators) in a string, `"quote the string"` as you did with the first `if` above.

Oh - and it's particular about the quotes - they must *exactly* match - you can't quote one side and not the other.

This applies to *string* arguments only - where the arguments are numerics or resolve to a numeric, the quotes are *not* used. If they are used with numeric arguments, the arguments will be compared *alphabetically* so `98` is **greater** than `123` because `9` is greater than `1`.

Comment: I think that answers a bit of my problem. But I load it up, and play test it through, I do the things my users (mainly teens and middle schoolers) will do--mash stuff, because why not!

Comment: Sorry, it sent before I could finish.  So when I get to the log in screen, i can put in USER as the un and ID as the password. No problem. But a kid may not. They may type: Mr. Last Name  --- and I want it to register that string as an incorrect entry and then says ACCESS denied, then jumps them back to the menu page where a counter now appears saying they have 4 attempts left. But if it won't accept anything that is a string. so is you line:     if [/i] string1 operator string2 dothis      exactly what i should put in so that i get the desired effect?

Comment: (eg) `if /I "%un%" == "ID" (` matches the contents of `un` to the literal `ID` in a case-insensitive manner, so only `ID` (in any case) will pass as `true` to the password-check. If `un` contains spaces however it won't *crash* (well there *are* ways of forcing it) but since `any string containing spaces` will not match `ID` then the password won't be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Always enquote variables in your `IF` expressions.

```
IF /i "%un%" == "ID" ...
IF /i "%pw%" == "PASSWORD" ...
```

or even better use delayed expansion here

```
IF /i "!un!" == "ID" ...
IF /i "!pw!" == "PASSWORD" ...
```

Comment: ...except if they are numerical.

Comment: un and pw will both be alpha-numerical when it comes time for the actual use in the escape room.

Comment: @Magoo You are right, but even then I would test them before I put them into an `IF`

Comment: what is the benefit of enquoting my variables?

Comment: I enquoted the line from my menu to be      if /I "%answer%" == "1" . . . but then my line    set var=%var: =%       which makes spaces before and after go away, and then the answer does not match. Whereas before I could type [space][space]1[space] hit enter and it would take me to where I wanted.

Comment: `set var=%var: =%` has no effect for the `answer` variable, you should change it to `set "answer=!answer: =!"`